# sed append a line after a block

Tags: text-processing, sed

In a directory, I have too many `site.ini.append.php` (about 100 files).

They all look like:

```
[block1]
blabla[]
blabla[]=blabla
...
blabla[]=blabla

[block2]
blabla[]
blabla[]=blabla
...
blabla[]=blabla

[block3]
blabla[]
blabla[]=blabla
...
blabla[]=blabla
```

However, `[block1]` has different number of entries depending on the file. It's the same thing for the other blocks.

I need to add a new line at the end of `[block2]`:

```
[block2]
blabla[]
blabla[]=blabla
...
blabla[]=blabla
blabla[]=new_entry
```

And I cannot just use line number because, as I said, blocks have different entries, and `[block2]` may have 20 lines in a file, and 10 in another etc...

I was thinking about somthing like this

```
sed -n '/^\[block2\]$/,/^$/ a blabla[]=new_entry' path/to/one_of_the_site.ini.append.php
```

But it doesn't work, obviously, because `/^\[block2\]$/,/^$/` is not an address.

How do I do it (preferably using sed)?

**UPDATE**

As explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416105/sed-append-a-line-after-a-block?noredirect=1#comment746839_416105), **/^[block2]$/,/^$/** is a valid address.

However, neither **a**, nor **i** fixes the issue for me

```
sed -n '/^\[block2\]$/,/^$/ a blabla[]=new_entry' path/to/one_of_the_site.ini.append.php 

sed -n '/^\[block2\]$/,/^$/ i blabla[]=new_entry' path/to/one_of_the_site.ini.append.php
```

> Environment

```
$ sed --version
GNU sed version 4.1.5
Copyright (C) 2003 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE,
to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: Your one liner works... `/^\[block2\]$/,/^$/` _is_ a valid address. It doesn't do what you want because it `a`ppends to all lines in that range. What you need here is to `i`nsert _before_ the empty line _in that range_. Very simple.

Comment: @don_crissti the question is how do I insert before the empty line in that range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 sed  '/block2/,/^$/s/^$/blabla[]=new_entry\n/g' filename
```

Above oneliner works fine .it matches the line between block2 and newline and then replaces newline with blabla[]=new_entry\n. Let me know for any issues

output

```
[block1]
blabla[]
blabla[]=blabla
...
blabla[]=blabla

[block2]
blabla[]
blabla[]=blabla
...
blabla[]=blabla
blabla[]=new_entry

[block3]
blabla[]
blabla[]=blabla
...
blabla[]=blabla
```

Answer (score 3):

Following @don_crissti's suggestion, this seems to work in GNU sed and the BSD one on my Mac:

```
sed -e $'/^\\\[block2\\\]$/,/^$/ {/^$/i\\\nnew line\n}' < input
```

However, it does depend on the empty line being there, I'm not sure if your file has it if the block we're looking for is the last one.

We need sed to get an actual newline to start and terminate the `i` command, so I used the ANSI-C quoting `$''` to make one (supported by ksh/zsh/bash). In a standard shell, you'll have to manually insert one.

Comment: I get an error :( `sed: -e expression #1, char 0: unmatched `{'`

Comment: @smarber, check the `$` in front of the quote, we need it to give sed a hard newline. Otherwise it takes the final `}` as part of the line being inserted.

Comment: @don_crissti, ah thanks. Bash leaves the backslash intact in `$'\['` and I didn't seem to think it through.

Comment: No problem. I recommend using the proper syntax (multiple expressions or separate lines) anytime `i`, `a` or `c` are used - less room for error and less confusing to newbs.